# Python get a python script running while another is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, assistant

I have been trying to make a personal assistant. I made a alarm clock a days ago, but its working like its testing if the date is the same like the real time. And my problem is that i would also use the main script while the alarm clock is check. But is there a way to do that? Like a module system or something else?

Comment: Either run two scripts of learn about [threading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions, Threads

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Threading

or async like gevent

http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/